# What is the url with which I can access my expess app (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express, url, routes, ip

I have deployed my Nodejs Express app on GoDaddy using ssh access to configure the whole thing. But I can't find the URL that leads me to my app.

it works perfectly on my computer where I access the app via the link http://localhost:3000

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const httpRequest = require("request");
const app = new express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.set("view engine","ejs");

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.use(express.static("public"));

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
//headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, 
PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

// Pass to next layer of middleware
next();
});

app.get("/",(request,response)=>{
 response.send("hello world!");
});


http.listen(port,function(){
 console.log(server.address());
 console.log("listening on port "+port);

});
```

I have the domain name of my server and I thought that adding ":3000" at the end of it will let me access the app but obviously it doesn't, I wanna know how to access it.

Comment: What is your Server OS? Is it dedicated server?  If your server is shared one then PORT 3000 or Whatever port is set in env. that need to be allow to public access. You may will contact to GoDaddy Customer Care to enable the port for public access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ip address of your GoDaddy virtual machine. 
to find it follow the instruction below:

1. Log in to your GoDaddy account.
2. In your My Products page, click Servers.
3. Next to the server you want to use, click Manage. The server IP address appears in the
4. Details tab. You may need to scroll down to see the address in the list.

Usege:

```
http://youripaddress:3000
```

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work , I still can't access my app

Comment: Then try to open the port as described above. or make sure it's opened:
sudo ufw status

Comment: when i execute sudo I get :
    bash: sudo : command not found

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: BTW, you can run your application on port 80 and it's going to work. can you try it?

Comment: I naturally get the error EACCES permission denied as it has to be exectued with sudo , and sudo doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

You might have to open the port first. The way you do it depends on what you use, with Linux-like OS and ufw you could do

> sudo ufw allow 3000

You can find more information and docs here:

[ufw - Uncomplicated Firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html.en)